# CTBarChart not found inside POI schemas

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I am currently using POI to edit data in embedded charts inside a PPTX file using XSLF. I found an example using a template ppt with a pie chart and it worked great. I also tried to edit a line chart and it worked. However, when I tried to edit a embedded bar chart, I found that CTBarChart.class is not implemented inside of schemas(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingxml.x2006.chart.CTBarChart.class).

I am wondering if I have to write my own XML parser or find a different library or if CTBarChart is part of another file inside POI that I did not find.

Comment: I found the ooxml schemas 1.0 jar which contains CTBarChart.class, I added that to the dependency and it is now working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [Apache POI FAQ Entry](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025) on this very issue!

Quoting the important part from that FAQ:

> There are two jar files available, as described in the components overview section. The full jar of all of the schemas is ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar, and it is currently around 15mb. The smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar is only about 4mb. This latter jar file only contains the typically used parts though.
>
> Many users choose to use the smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar to save space. However, the poi-ooxml-schemas jar only contains the XSDs and classes that are typically used, as identified by the unit tests. Every so often, you may try to use part of the file format which isn't included in the minimal poi-ooxml-schemas jar. In this case, you should switch to the full ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar. Longer term, you may also wish to submit a new unit test which uses the extra parts of the XSDs, so that a future poi-ooxml-schemas jar will include them.

So, short term you need to switch from the small `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar to the full `ooxml-schemas` one. Long term, you need to submit a unit test to Apache POI which uses that class, so it gets automatically included in future small jars